# Problems writing to network device using sockets

Tags: android, sockets, io

I have a wireless device communicating over port 22 connected to my network. Once the device starts up, it immediately starts sending log data. Once this device is sent a command, it stops logging and responds accordingly. This all works, I have tested it using a telnet client.

My problem is that I can't seem to send it a command properly in my app. I am reading the log data as planned, but when I send it a command, in this case the command "r", it continues outputting log data instead what it should be showing me for that particular command. This has to mean that I am not properly sending the command. This is my code for the task that sends it the command and logs the output in the android logcat:

```
public class ReceiveVarTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
    String dstAddress;
    int Port;

    ReceiveVarTask(String addr, int port) {
        dstAddress = addr;
        Port = port;
    }

    protected Void doInBackground(Void... vars){
        Socket socket = null;
        String command = "r";

        try {
            Log.i(TAG, "Connecting to port 22");
            socket = new Socket(dstAddress, Port);
            Log.i(TAG, "Connected to port 22");

            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);

            InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

            writer.println(command);

            String line = reader.readLine();

            Log.i(TAG, line);

            while(line!=null && !isCancelled()){

                line = reader.readLine();
                Log.i(TAG, line);
            }

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            if (socket != null) {
                try {
                    socket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void arg) {
        taskRunning = false;
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Why is it not registering the command?

UPDATE:

I have used several telnet clients for testing, and the server is reading the 'r' command as expected on some. It works using a windows telnet client, and it works using the vSSH app by Velestar. Interestingly enough, when testing this with the android telnet client by ClockworkMod, the server is not registering the command either.

Could it be something to do with encoding?

Do I need any additional permissions to work with sockets? I have android.permission.INTERNET declared in the manifest.

UPDATE 2:

The developer of of the hardware just told me that the hardware is expecting the command to be ASCII encoded and CR terminated. So I will try changing PrintWrite initialization to:

```
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter( new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), "ASCII")), true);
```

and the print command to:

```
writer.print(command+"\r");
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the the encoding type to "US-ASCII" and adding a carriage return instead of a new line did the trick. I'm able to read and write data as expected.

Answer (score -1):

From my understanding of your problem description, you have a telnet server, and when a telnet client connects to that server, the server start sending the client log data. The client may send an "r" to the server to stop the log stream.

- I suggest you first confirm using another telnet client that sending an "r" does stop the server from generating more log data.
- You could use Wireshark to check if the "r" command is indeed sent.

Comment: I have used several telnet clients, and this does work. I works using a windows telnet client, and it works using the vSSH app by Velestar. Interestingly enough, when testing this with the android telnet client by  ClockworkMod, the server is not registering the command either.

Comment: Off topic...speaking of ssh/telnet client for Android, definitely try Juice SSH, it's free. Best ssh/telnet client, ever, for Android. =)    Back to the topic, have your tried pcaping what your Android telnet client is sending and compare it to other telnet clients? It maybe as simple as line ending or whatever telnet setting...but I really can't think of anything right now without seeing more test result. Please post update here in case you find out what the problem was!

Comment: I am away from the hardware at the moment, so I will not be able to test until later tonight. However, the developer of of the hardware just told me that the hardware is expecting the command to be ASCII encoded and CR terminated. So I will try changing PrintWrite initialization to PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(                   new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), "ASCII")), true); and the print command to writer.print(command+"\r");

Comment: If that doesn't work I will pcap the clients that have been working for me.